# Function Template Specialization Syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Given this function template:

```
template<typename A> void func (A param) {...}
```

In order to write an specialization, we can use either this idiom (A)

```
template<> void func<> (int param) {...}
```

Or this one (B)

```
template<> void func<int> (int param) {..}
```

Is there any difference between A and B? If both are the same, what's the preferred syntax and why?

Comment: It's just template argument deduction. Use whichever you think other people would find easiest to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A.) `template<> void func<> (int param) {...}`

B.) `template<> void func<int> (int param) {..}`

**Is there any difference between A and B?**

Technically B has the template argument explicitly specified while A has it's argument reduced, but to the user it's merely how you present your function.

**If both are the same, what's the preferred syntax and why?**

Since defining both would result in a multiple definition error (i.e. they're the same function), it's really up to personal preference as to how you present the function.

I'm personally partial to B since it fully defines and clearly states intention of function, but again that's my *personal* preference

Hope that can help