# consequence of reducing template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I read these SO posts [ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935421/function-template-specialization), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124256/need-to-understand-function-template-resolution-rules) ], and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008196/function-template-specialization-syntax) one, but was surprised to get the following results:

1. first ordering:

   ```
   template<typename T> // template (a)
   void f(T);

   template<typename T> // template (b)
   f(T*);             

   template<>           // template (c)
   f<>(int*);

   // ...

   int *p;  f<int*>(p); // calls (a)
   ```
2. second ordering:

   ```
   template<typename T> // template (a)
   void f(T);

   template<>           // template (c)
   f<>(int*);

   template<typename T> // template (b)
   f(T*); 

   // ...

   int *p;  f<int*>(p); // calls (c)
   ```

Why template (a) got chosen on the first ordering (instead of template (c))?

Comment: In the first example, `(c)` is a specialization of `(b)` (the latter having been selected by overload resolution as a better match). But `f<int*>(p)` can't possibly call `(b)` (that would require an argument of type `int**`). In the second example, `(c)` is a specialization of `(a)` (since `(b)` is not visible at the point of declaration).

Comment: Can you elaborate? what is the need for `int**`?

Comment: The `(b)` overload with `T==int*` takes a parameter of type `int**`. You are passing `int*`, so `(b)` is not viable. Recall that specializations don't participate in overload resolution - only primary templates are. Once the primary is chosen, the compiler looks further to see whether it should instantiate one of its specializations.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.